# Windows apps do not minimize properly

Tags: windows-11, desktop, window

I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> shortcut to minimize apps. Recently, I've been facing the problem that using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> does not properly minimize the window. Rather, it de-focuses the window, as if I just clicked on some region outside the window. Using the "Resize Window"-button (middle one in taskbar) fixes the problem until it happens again a few tries later. It now happens very frequently enough that it is now a major inconvenience.

Using the "Show Desktop" from the right taskbar corner shows the desktop but does not minimize properly either, if I open another app, it's window opens over the previous window.

Any solutions?

Comment: Seems to be working fine here. Try DISM then  SFC.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Does this behavior happen while in Safe Mose?

Comment: Doe Win+D work for displaying Desktop?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @John Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: @Ramhound I could not reproduce it in safe mode. What do you suggest next?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik win+D shows the desktpp, but fails to actually minimize the window. It's the same as the show desktop button on the right corner of taskbar, as i mentioned.